# Exceptions active after have been caught in async methods

Tags: c#, async-await, clr

Now I know it's a hack to use `Marshal.GetExceptionCode()` in the first place, but the question is not about it (Visual Studio debugger also detects an active exception)

```
private static async Task TestAsync()
{
    Log("TestAsync.Before");

    await HandleExceptionAsync();

    Log("TestAsync.After");
}

private static async Task HandleExceptionAsync()
{
    try
    {
        Log("HandleExceptionAsync.Try");
        await ThrowAsync();
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        Log("HandleExceptionAsync.Catch");
    }

    Log("HandleExceptionAsync.AfterCatch");
}

private static async Task ThrowAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Delayed exception");
}

private static void Log(string step)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{step}: {Marshal.GetExceptionCode()}");
}
```

Output

```
TestAsync.Before: 0
HandleExceptionAsync.Try: 0
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Interactive.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.ni.dll
HandleExceptionAsync.Catch: -532462766
HandleExceptionAsync.AfterCatch: -532462766
TestAsync.After: -532462766
The thread 9292 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

***The exception stays active throughout await chain even though it's been caught.***
I checked the generated code and it does not give a clue why this is happening, relevant part (generated `MoveNext` for `HandleExceptionAsync` state machine):

```
  void IAsyncStateMachine.MoveNext()
  {
    int num1 = this.\u003C\u003E1__state;
    try
    {
      if (num1 == 0)
        ;
      try
      {
        TaskAwaiter awaiter;
        int num2;
        if (num1 != 0)
        {
          Program.Log("HandleExceptionAsync.Try");
          awaiter = Program.ThrowAsync().GetAwaiter();
          if (!awaiter.IsCompleted)
          {
            this.\u003C\u003E1__state = num2 = 0;
            this.\u003C\u003Eu__1 = awaiter;
            Program.\u003CHandleExceptionAsync\u003Ed__1 stateMachine = this;
            this.\u003C\u003Et__builder.AwaitUnsafeOnCompleted<TaskAwaiter, Program.\u003CHandleExceptionAsync\u003Ed__1>(ref awaiter, ref stateMachine);
            return;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          awaiter = this.\u003C\u003Eu__1;
          this.\u003C\u003Eu__1 = new TaskAwaiter();
          this.\u003C\u003E1__state = num2 = -1;
        }
        awaiter.GetResult();
        awaiter = new TaskAwaiter();
      }
      catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
      {
        Program.Log("HandleExceptionAsync.Catch");
      }
      Program.Log("HandleExceptionAsync.AfterCatch");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      this.\u003C\u003E1__state = -2;
      this.\u003C\u003Et__builder.SetException(ex);
      return;
    }
    this.\u003C\u003E1__state = -2;
    this.\u003C\u003Et__builder.SetResult();
  }
```

I don't see this being related to the synchronization context either (in this case it's a console app so continuations are scheduled on the pool), my best guess there's some call stack manipulation happening, but I can't find any good info on this.

I'd appreciate if anybody could explain why this is happening and provide link to docs explaining how this is implemented in CLR / the compiler

**UPD1:** Added screenshots of the VS debugger showing an active exception in async, showing nothing in sync

**Async**
[image: Repro inside the VS 2015 debugger]

**Sync**
[image: No exception in sync version of the code]

Comment: `GetExceptionCode` has [undefined behavior outside of the filter of a structured exception handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679356(v=vs.85).aspx). If you have a scenario that causes an "active" exception after it's been caught, please post a repro of the issue.

Comment: @StephenCleary this particular code shows the exception as active in VS debugger ($exception variable). Does not this repro for you?

Comment: To me, "active" means it's being thrown (or - in extended usage - has been caught). Are you seeing any behavior like this, or is it just the `$exception` debugger variable?

Comment: @StephenCleary just the variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you put a breakpoint at `Log("HandleExceptionAsync.AfterCatch");`, the callstack explains the trick:

```
ConsoleApp1.exe!ConsoleApp1.Program.Log(string step) Line 107   C#
ConsoleApp1.exe!ConsoleApp1.Program.HandleExceptionAsync() Line 95  C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(object stateMachine)  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction(System.Action action, bool allowInlining, ref System.Threading.Tasks.Task currentTask)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree() Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo()   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(bool bUserDelegateExecuted) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.TrySetException(object exceptionObject) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.SetException(System.Exception exception) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.SetException(System.Exception exception)    Unknown
ConsoleApp1.exe!ConsoleApp1.Program.ThrowAsync() Line 101   C#
... (continues until the timer of Task.Delay)
```

See the bottom frame? We're still in ThrowAsync, even though we're logging from `HandleExceptionAsync`. How is that possible? The answer is also in the callstack:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.TrySetException(object exceptionObject) Unknown
```

To put it simple, because of the `await` keyword, your `HandleExceptionAsync` method is chopped as below:

```
void HandleExceptionAsync1()
{
    Log("HandleExceptionAsync.Try");
}

void HandleExceptionAsync2()
{
    Log("HandleExceptionAsync.AfterCatch");
}
```

Of course, this is way more complex than that. In truth, the method isn't chopped and is simply transformed into a state-machine. However, for this demonstration, this is sensibly equivalent.

`HandleExceptionAsync2` needs to be executed after `ThrowAsync`. Therefore, `HandleExceptionAsync2` will be chained as a continuation. Something like:

```
ThrowAsync().ContinueWith(HandleExceptionAsync2);
```

(again, **this is much more complex than that**. I'm merely simplifying for the explanation)

The "problem" is, when the runtime completes the task returned by ThrowAsync:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.TrySetException(object exceptionObject)
```

The continuation will actually be inlined, and executed in the same callstack (see the frames above). This is an optimization often done by the TPL, for performance reasons. Because of that, when calling `Log("HandleExceptionAsync.AfterCatch");`, **you're actually still in the catch block of `ThrowAsync`**, hence the behavior you see.

Comment: thanks a ton, that is one very good explanation and the whole thing now makes perfect sense to me, I was looking at the generated state machine for a while and it just did not occur to me that the continuation would be executed from inside the generated by the compiler catch!